# Web Api, How to return enum text value instead of enum index value from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, enums

I notice that my Web Api method that return HttpResponseMessage convert enum value to int (order of value). But I would like to return enum text value.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {MyEnum.Someting, MyEnum.Someting2});
```

What should I setup for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Enum.GetName method

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), 0), Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), 1)});
```

If this is what you are looking for ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 16):

If you are returning and receiving the data in `Json`, you can use `StringEnumConverter`. Defining a model like this:

```
class Output
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public MyEnum[] Enums { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Output { Enums = new MyEnum[] { MyEnum.Someting, MyEnum.Someting2 } }); ;
}
```

Allows you instruct the json serializer to converts enums to and from its name string value.

Moreover, if you do not want to define the output model, in your `WebApiConfig.Register(config)` method, you can add this lines and also works:

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
```

and for .Net Core Web API use this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions( op => {
      op.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return the name of a value defined in `MyEnum`:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
    new string[] {MyEnum.Someting.ToString(), MyEnum.Someting2.ToString()});
```

If you have a number of variables of type `MyEnum`, then you can simply to a `ToString` on those variables:

```
MyEnum var1 = MyEnum.Something;
MyEnum var2 = MyEnum.Something2;

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
       new string[] {var1.ToString(), var2.ToString()});
```

If you wanted to return the names of each value defined in `MyEnum` you can use:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { TextValueOfSomething = MyEnum.Someting.ToString(), TextValueOfSomething2 = MyEnum.Someting2.ToString() });
```

You can't return `new {MyEnum.Something.ToString(), MyEnum.Something2.ToString()}` because you can't declare an anoymous object in this way. If you just want an array of strings then you would use `new[] {MyEnum.Something.ToString(), MyEnum.Something2.ToString()}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following helper method:

```
public static class Enums
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

Then include descriptions in your enum, such as this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Something 1")]
    Something1 = 1,
    [Description("Something 2")]
    Something2 = 2
}
```

And finally simply call:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new 
{ 
    MyEnum.Something1.GetDescription(), 
    MyEnum.Something2.GetDescription()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an extension for enums :

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum @enum)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = @enum.GetType().GetField(@enum.ToString());

        if (null != fi)
        {
            object[] attrs = fi.GetCustomAttributes
                (typeof (DescriptionAttribute), true);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute) attrs[0]).Description;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetAllValues<TEnum>()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
    }
}
```

Your Enum :

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("foobar1 text")]
    foobar1= 1,
    [Description("foobar2 text")]
    foobar2= 2,
    [Description("foobar3 text")]
    foobar3= 3,
    [Description("foobar4 text")]
    foobar3= 4
}
```

Then call like this :

```
 MyEnum.foobar2.GetDescription()
```

Should return `foobar2 text`

**Other solution is :**

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum.foobar2))
```

to return `foobar2`